# What will "the weather be" or "be the weather"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, interrogatives

The question about the weather should be

1- **What/how will the weather be?**

While I found a lot of examples with the form of:

2- **What/how will be the weather?**

Doesn't the grammatical form of questions (Wh + aux v + sub + main v) tell us that (1) is the only correct form?

Comment: Who says it _should_ be? "What's the weather going to be like?" or "What sort of weather will we have?" (and probably other versions) are equally possible.

Comment: Well, the second alternative is a bit Yoda, or Somerset ;)

Comment: Yes you a correct. 1 is correct, and 2 is wrong.  If you found No. 2 somewhere, then it's likely an error or something written by a non-native speaker.

Comment: Please note: Any question with a be verb calls for inverting the subject and the verb.

Comment: @Lambie - yes, that's the issue here. The interrogative requires inversion of the verb and subject.  "I am", becomes "Who am I?".  "It will be" becomes "What will it be"

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but the first is very much more common.

When the question word is not the subject, then the subject and auxiliary are inverted. So your 1 is a question inviting an answer of the form:

> The weather will be X

"Weather" is the subject, and the answer the complement.

When the question word is the subject, it does not invert, so your 2 is asking a question inviting an answer of the form

> X will be the weather.

A statement of this form is rare (the only common example I can think of is something like *The problem will be the weather*, and the only question that is likely to be a reply to is *What will the problem be?*) so your no 2 is correspondingly very unlikely to be said by a native speaker. If you have found examples, they are probably by non-native speakers.

Comment: What will be the weather when the knight-at-arms leaves the withered sedge by the lake? (Thanks Keats). It's pretty poetical but not used in standard conversation.